# How to use smarty code inside jQuery's append method in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, smarty

I've following code of appending rows to the HTML table:

```
    $('.btnAdd').click(function () {
    $('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append('<tr id="Row2">' +
                      '<td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>' +
                      '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>' +
                      '<td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>' +
                      '<td>' +
                        '<div class="btn-group">' +
                          '<select name="units[]" class="form-control">' +
                            '<option value="" {if $all_volume_units.id==\'\'} selected=\'selected\'{/if}>Select Unit</option>' +
                            '{foreach from=$all_volume_units item=units key=key} ' +
'<option value="{$units.id}" {if $units.id == $all_volume_units.id} selected="selected" {/if}>{$units.unit}</option>' +
'{/foreach}' +
'</select>' +
'</div>' +
'</td>' +
'<td>' +
'<input type="text" name="amount[]" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/>' +
'</td>' +
'</tr>');

            });
```

The above HTML code is working fine when I append row to the HTML table. But there is some issue with smarty code. It's not working at all. The smarty code is considered as a string. SO can anyone please help me by correcting my code so that the smarty code should be workable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you think that javascript would execute a php template ? client's dont interface with the server directly, you need a bridge. This template will need to be returned from an ajax call that returns the smarty view.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:But if I simply append the HTML with smarty code. Then it should work out there in smarty template as it is gettin the smarty code. Other care will be taken by PHP code there. Then why should I use ajax here?

Comment: The code is probably between {literal} tags or in a separate .js file, so it's not parsed by smarty.

Comment: For such a scenario I would set the entire tr as a smarty capture http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.capture.tpl and pass it in combination with the escape modifier http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl to the javascript method. `$('#blacklistgrid > tbody:last').append({$smarty.capture.tr|escape:'javascript'})`